# How to get substring of SimplePie description?

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

This the code to get the full description or content of the feed. However I would only like the first 15 characters from the start. Is my code correct?

```
</a> · <?php echo $item->get_description(str.substr(0,14)); ?>
```

Comment: @DipeshParmar Yea it gave me the full description/It didnt give me 15 characters

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php echo substr($item->get_description($str),0,15); ?>
```

Comment: That still gets the full feed.

Comment: Answer is modified please try it now

Comment: I set it to 0,15 but it does work any text or sometime with only shows a word. I think that the image is blocking it. Also there seems to be weird letters like "&nbs" and "--->" randomly. Do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have HTML tags wrapping your text. So you actually have more than 15 characters including the HTML markup. You can strip the HTML out first using [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to get just 15 characters of text:

```
<?php echo substr(strip_tags($item->get_description($str)),0,15); ?>
```

Alternately if you want to keep the HTML markup, you would have to get the opening tag and then do a forward lookup of the ending tag, get the position in the string, and truncate anything after that.